# TableView not displaying data from Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I am building an app which uses Firebase's database service. I am trying to load the data into a table view but I am unable to do so. I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong. The code is also not giving me any errors. I've checked the database permissions on Firebase and they seem to be good. Here's my code:

```
    import UIKit
import Firebase

struct postStruct {
    let word : String!
    let wordType : String!
}

class sentenceBuilderViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var wordSearchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var wordsTableView: UITableView!

    var posts = [postStruct]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        wordsTableView.reloadData()
        getWordsFromDatabase()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        wordsTableView.delegate = self
        wordsTableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func getWordsFromDatabase() {
        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
            databaseRef.child("wordList").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {
                snapshot in


                let word = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["word"] as? String
                let wordType = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    )!["wordType"] as? String
                self.posts.insert(postStruct(word: word, wordType: wordType), at: 0)

            })
        wordsTableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return posts.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = wordsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

        let wordLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        wordLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].word

        let wordTypeLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        wordTypeLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].wordType

        return cell!
    }

}
```

Any help and inputs would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: put `.reloadData()` inside `obsereSingleEvent` completion block.

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht Thank you for the quick response. I tried doing that but it still isn't working. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are just observing a single event here:

```
databaseRef.child("wordList").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
```

What this does is that it justs goes through your database and once it finds any child, it displays that one without going further. What you need to do is change it to observe like this:

```
 func getAllWordsFromDatabase() {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("wordList").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
        snapshot in
        let word = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["word"] as? String
        let wordType = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["wordType"] as? String
        self.posts.append(postStruct(word: word, wordType: wordType))

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.wordsTableView.reloadData()
        }
        })
}
```

Try implementing this and it should work.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async {` isn't needed in Firebase closures as UI calls always run on the main thread. Other than that, good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Move the "getWordsFromDatabase()" line in "viewDidLoad" function to AFTER you assign the delegate and data source, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    wordsTableView.delegate = self
    wordsTableView.dataSource = self
    getWordsFromDatabase()
}
```

Also you can try to add a "reloadData()" method in the databaseRef block on the main queue, like this:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("wordList").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in
            let word = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)!["word"] as? String
            let wordType = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                )!["wordType"] as? String
            self.posts.insert(postStruct(word: word, wordType: wordType), at: 0)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                wordsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
```

Comment: Okay. I tried this as well. This time, the word is showing up but the problem is that only one word is showing up from the database, which happens to be the first word in the Firebase database. Can't understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @ojassethi123 try printing the "self.posts" array after you have added all the rows from the database to see if you actually got everything in there or if there is something wrong in the code where you get all the "words" from database. Also, try to use "self.posts.append()" instead of "self.posts.insert". Might change things up.

Comment: Hey. I tried printing the self.posts array and its only printing the first item from the list in the console. I also tried changing self.posts.insert to self.posts.append() but nothing seems to change. Something is very wrong here. I would appreciate it if you could help me further. Thanks!

Comment: It may be something with how you query the data from the DB. I'm not very familiar with the firebase SDK api, but maybe you should try something different on how you get the data, maybe something like: databaseRef.child("wordList").queryOrderedByKey() only.

Comment: Okay. Is it something because of me casting the snapshot.value as an NSDictionary? Should it be cast into an NSArray?

Comment: That should not be the issue, the app should crash if you force cast it to the wrong kind of class. Try to do only the first part, the "let newData = databaseRef.child("wordList")" and maybe print that object or add a breakpoint to see in xcode what information that object holds (add breakpoint, start app and wait til it stops at that line and then hover the mouse over the object).

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for your help!